# Storing varying data types

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, types, database-design

We are currently building a PostgreSQL database that allows us to create profiles for hardware. Each profile exists of a few different properties which are all dynamically added to the profile through the UI. Each property can be of a different type (string, integer, text, ...)

How would I most efficiently store these properties in a relational database?

I've read [Storing diverse value types in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486307/storing-diverse-value-types-in-a-database) and I'm charmed by the single answer there but I'm not at all confident that this is the ideal solution. Are there any pros/cons using the separate-table-per-type approach over the other solutions? Anyone has real world experience with this and minds shedding some light on the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way is single table with both key and value being varchar and/or text.

The only big disadvantage of table-per-type in that comment I can think of is that it's hard to constraint the uniqueness of the key in pair with the entity this key-value entry belongs to.

Table inheritance (but still with table-per-type) would be another way to go and IMHO it's brutally type-safe and compliant with postgres and ORM concepts:

```
CREATE TABLE key_values(user_id integer references users(id), key varchar(255), type varchar(255), CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(user_id, key));
CREATE TABLE key_values_int(value integer) INHERITS (key_values);
CREATE TABLE key_values_string(value varchar(255)) INHERITS (key_values);
and so on...
```

This perfectly maps to JPA.

Comment: Is it possible in this system to get all key_value records for a given user_id along with the values from the respective child table? For example get alle key/value pairs for user_id 50?

Comment: Yes, that's what is the `type` column for, it should serve as a discriminator. All comprehensive ORM libs are capable of fetching the objects from that kind of table structure: normally, first query from the ORM engine will be select on key_values table, then based on the `type` column of entries it will fetch values from the respective value tables.

Comment: Okay, so you'll always have to run multiple queries? I'll have to experiment a little on performance but my guess is that the advantage you have with this system and the appropriate indexes are higher than the all-in-a-text column approach suggested by @Erwin_Brandstetter in the other answer

Comment: Yes, in the perfect ORM engine it should ne `n + 1` queries, where `n` is amount of distinct types you got with the query on the master table. So the number of queries shouldn't even directly depend on the amount of records you fetch. But perfect things are sometimes too good to be true.  So if reality in your framework set is far from perfect then you'll have to go for all-in-text or for column-per-type in a single table or for the approach you referenced in your question. It  depends on your domain model.

Answer (score 4):

Use a column of [data type **`text`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html).

Every data type in PostgreSQL has text representation - or else a plain `pg_dump` would fail. Also, how would the user type in the value in the first place?

I have had several use cases like that for a couple of years now. No problems.
You can store the actual data type in addition and cast the text representation if needed.

One disadvantage might be that the on-disc space for text representation will be higher for some types. But the overhead for multiple columns / tables may easily make up for that.

#### Additional answer to question in comment

PostgreSQL is extremely versatile with indexing. I would solve a case like you mention in the comment with a [**partial index on an expression**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html):

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_col_propx_idx ON tbl (cast(col AS int))
WHERE  prop_type_id = 23;  -- 23 signifying "propertyX"
```

And `prop_type_id` would be a foreign key to a look-up table (foreign-key referenced):

```
CREATE TABLE prop_type(
   prop_type_id int PRIMARY KEY,
   prop_type text NOT NULL);
```

`prop_type_id` could also be an [`enum` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html). The handling of [enums has been much improved](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-9-1.html#AEN107265) in the latest version.

Then a query like this would be lightening fast:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  prop_type_id = 23   -- 23 signifying "propertyX"
AND    col::int BETWEEN 50 AND 100
```

In addition, such an index would automatically **validate the data type** and throw an error if you'd try to enter string that doesn't match the type.

---

**Alternatively**, consider a document type like [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) or [`json` / `josnb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) (typically superior in modern Postgres).

Comment: What about indexing? In some cases it would prove usefull if there was an index on the value column to ease lookups like "give me all items with propertyX (integer) where the value is between 50 and 100" ?